# On the inequality $I(n^2) \geq (6 - s(q^k))/3$, where $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number and $I(x)$ is the abundancy index of $x$

Tags: number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

In what follows, we denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$, the *deficiency* of $x$ by $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$, the *aliquot sum* of $x$ by $s(x)=\sigma(x)-x$, and the *abundancy index* of $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.

Let $m = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number given in *Eulerian form*, i.e. $q$ is the *special/Euler prime* satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Since $\gcd(q^k,\sigma(q^k))=1$, we get
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)}=\frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2}.$$
But
$$\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2} \geq \frac{q^k + 1}{2} \geq \frac{5 + 1}{2} = 3,$$
so that
$$\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)} \leq \frac{n^2}{3}.$$

However, $D(n^2) = 2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)$, so that dividing both sides of the last inequality by $n^2 > 0$ yields
$$\frac{2 - I(n^2)}{s(q^k)} \leq \frac{1}{3}.$$
Multiplying both sides of the last inequality by $s(q^k) > 0$ gives
$$2 - I(n^2) \leq \frac{s(q^k)}{3}.$$

We finally obtain
$$I(n^2) \geq 2 - \frac{s(q^k)}{3} = 2 - \frac{q^k - 1}{3(q - 1)} = \frac{6(q - 1) - (q^k - 1)}{3(q - 1)} = \frac{-q^k + 6q - 5}{3(q - 1)} := f(q, k).$$

Note that
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial q} = -\frac{(k-1)q^{k+1} - kq^k + q}{3q(q-1)^2} < 0$$
and that
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial k} = -\frac{q^k \ln q}{3(q - 1)} < 0,$$
which means that
$$f(q, k) = \frac{-q^k + 6q - 5}{3(q - 1)}$$
is a *decreasing function of both $q$ and $k$*.

This implies that
$$I(n^2) \geq \lim_{q \rightarrow \infty}{f(q,k)},$$
which does not exist when $k > 1$, and
$$I(n^2) \geq \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}{f(q,k)},$$
which likewise does not exist.

Here are my:

> **QUESTIONS:** Does this argument prove that $k=1$?  If it does not, how can the proof be mended to make it valid?

Comment: To be clear, do you notice that when $k\gt 1$, $\displaystyle\lim_{q\to\infty}f(q,k)=\lim_{k\to\infty}f(q,k)=-\infty$ ?

Comment: Yes, @mathlove.

Comment: Please write out your last comment as an actual answer (and include more details if needs be), so that I can upvote and then accept, @mathlove!  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $k\gt 1$, one has
$$\lim_{q\to\infty}f(q,k)=\lim_{k\to\infty}f(q,k)=-\infty.$$

So, I think that you cannot prove that $k=1$ from the two inequalities
$$I(n^2) \geq \lim_{q \rightarrow \infty}{f(q,k)}$$
and
$$I(n^2) \geq \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}{f(q,k)}$$